# How to search a 2D array inside a 2D array efficiently?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to search a 2D array inside a 2D array, and I have tried the following code to do so:

```java
loopX: for (int x = 0; x < str1.length - str2.length + 1; ++x)
            loopY: for (int y = 0; y < str1[x].length - str2[0].length + 1; ++y)
            {
                for (int xx = 0; xx < str2.length; ++xx)
                for (int yy = 0; yy < str2[0].length; ++yy)
                {
                    if (str1[x + xx][y + yy] != str2[xx][yy])
                    {
                        k++;
                        continue loopY;

                    }
                }

                // Found the submatrix!
                System.out.println("Found at: " + x + " " + y);
                break loopX;
            }
            System.out.println(k);
```

In this code `str1` is the larger 2D array inside which I am trying to search and match the smaller 2D array `str2`. Both are `char` arrays.

`k` is the element I need to keep track of in case, there is no match.

I would also like to know what can be the most efficient way to do so.

For this the algorithm I thought, that first I should match only the starting element of both the arrays, and when they match then only go and match other elements.

But, I am not able to write specific code for this.

I would appreciate if someone could help me in this.

Comment: Please see this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119138/5774004

Comment: @SreeraghAR that answer didn't help, I tried that method.